# Possible to export FireFox extensions and settings?

Tags: firefox

Want my FireFox at work to be in sync with my FireFox at my home. Is there a way to simply export all extensions and settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the files from your FireFox/Profiles folder to get the settings/saved passwords etc.

That contains settngs and passwords.  I believe you can do a similar process for extensions as well

Answer (score 2):

Try [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/)

Comment: Downloads as an .exe file so is not platform independent, and therefore is not itself an extension I can use both on Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Mozilla Weave](http://labs.mozilla.com/projects/weave/). An alternative is [Foxmarks](http://www.foxmarks.com) although I think that's limited to just bookmarks.

Comment: I don't believe that Mozilla Sync automatically reinstalls extensions used on the originating browser, well, as of 2012-04-04, does it?

Answer (score 1):

FEBE / CLEO  for plugin export/import

Answer (score -1):

Since extensions are stored in your profile, you could just make a copy of it to a Flash drive or something.